# Attach a program to a process stdout/stderr

Tags: c, unix, process

I have a program where I need to attach to stdout/stderr of a given pid (fetched from a file).
How this should be done?Is this even possible?

**EDIT 1:**

I have a monitor program that starts/stops a server program. However, the monitor can be closed/reopened and should hook to existent server stdout to read errors that are written on stdout (and also some output based on some monitor requests).

**EDIT 2:**

I built server and monitor so I have sources of both, the problem is that the server "answer" to some monitor requests on the stdout, I don't want to add another interprocess comunication part

Comment: What is it that you are trying to acheive? Exlaining your intent might help us suggest you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a process is running, there isn't a standard Unix way to intercept its output from another process and start capturing it after the target process has been started.

If you are starting these processes yourself, via `execve`, you can simply set up a pipe via `pipe(2)` and redirect its descriptors (via `dup2(2)`) to the child process' stdin and stdout. This way the parent will be able to write/read to the child's stdin/stdout through the pipe.

Regarding your question after the edit: this seems like a good fit for a Unix fifo file.

A fifo file (or a named pipe) appears like a file, but is implemented as a pipe under the bonnet.

So just create a fifo file (with the `mkfifo(1)` command), start the server application by redirecting its stdin and stdout descriptors to that file (with the `<` and `>` operators of the shell), and you'll be able to read from it anytime.

Comment: I'm already working on fifos, I would like to avoid them for monitoring part, but it looks is the only way I can do this :\

Comment: It looks like this is my only possibility, I hate this

Answer (score 1):

Never tried, but you may look at the /proc/$pid/ directory if it is possible (with proper permissions) to attach to the file descriptor entries there. Otherwise I couldn't imagine how this would be possible.

---

EDIT (after getting more details)

You state, that your process will be respnsible to start/stop that server process - THIS makes things a lot easier :)

As this is homework, I'll just draw the picture:

- create named pipes for ther server's *stdin* and *stdout*
- when starting the server, connect its *stdin/stdout* with the named pipes
- when starting your client, read/write from/to the named pipes

Comment: Mhh bad thing... I have to rewrite a really big part of code if this is the case

Comment: Yea I know this way, however because my teacher didn't write that when monitor is terminated the server SHOULDN'T terminate, I thought that when you close the monitor, the server should stop. They chosen (now) that this is not the case, and I was trying another way to avoid rewriting a big part of the monitor which expects answers on the stdout. It looks like is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option of configuring the server so that it sends output to a log file instead, or in addition to, stdout? On a unix box, you could run the server through `tee` to log stdout to a file:

```
$ server | tee server.log
```

Then it is a simple matter to tail server.log to get the latest output.

```
$ tail -f server.log
```

Comment: I suggest you update your logging code to output to both stdout and either a file or a named pipe.